# Translate feature of Chromium is not working on 16.04

Tags: chromium

Both Chrome and Chromium have this feature that translate pages to (e.g.) English and I have been using it before on other versions/flavors of Ubunutu.

However, now on 16.04 with unity, Chromium say the page is translated but in reality it doesn't happen and the page is in its original language. I tested this with `Chromium 58.0.3020.0` on multiple languages. Apparently, there has been a [bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=656922&can=1&start=0&num=100&q=gtTimeInfo&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&groupby=&sort=) which should have been solved by now. Any ideas?

Comment: Odd. I never faced this issue, I use `ubuntu and ubuntu-mate 16.04.2` in my work place and home, with both chrome and chromium, but never faced this issue. Are you using the point releases? Or the base 16.04

Comment: @SirajusSalekin, I don't know. I get it from [here](https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/download-chromium). Where it says "Easy Point and Click for latest build"

Comment: I meant what version of Ubuntu are you using. Maybe you're facing the bug because you're using `ubuntu 16.04`, and I don't because I use `ubuntu 16.04.2` ? If thats the case, you may try updating your OS.